# Why do I get the error You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard running a web project with visual studio 2019?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I recently started using the new VS 2019, but when it comes to run an ASP.NET MVC project I always get the error

```
The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

I don't understand this error, because my applications are built on .NET Framework 4.6.1, and I don't use the lib `netstandard`, which I happened to understand it's for .NET Core.

I get indeed no errors if I run it using VS 2017. How can I solve this?

Comment: what version of ,net standard are you using

Comment: I'm not using .NET standard in my projects